# Environment variables and RStudio

Tags: rstudio, rpython

I'm using RStudio and have been trying to use the rPython package to do some email handling for me. This involves unpacking some email attachments so I need to use a newer version of Python than 2.7.

I am on ubuntu so I've set environment variables in a bash script which I can see has worked:

bash

```
alias python=python3
export RPYTHON_PYTHON_VERSION=3
```

command line

```
echo $RPYTHON_PYTHON_VERSION
3
```

And yet, when I install rPython in RStudio it says:

Installing package into ‘/home/richardc/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/rPython_0.0-5.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 37109 bytes (36 Kb)

## opened URL

downloaded 36 Kb

- installing *source* package ‘rPython’ ...
  ** package ‘rPython’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
  **a specific python version to use was not provided**
  defaulting to the standard python in the system

So, despite python --version returning 3.4 and setting the environment variable it is defaulting to 2.7

I'm hoping that there is something straightforward I'm missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@nickbloom was actually close to it, but it is not `Sys.setenv(RPYTHON_PYTHON_PATH=3)` but `Sys.setenv(RPYTHON_PYTHON_VERSION=3)`

In my case (I have Python 3.5) it was:

```
> Sys.setenv(RPYTHON_PYTHON_VERSION=3.5)  
> install.packages('rPython')  
Installing package into ‘/usr/lib64/R/library’ (as ‘lib’ is unspecified) trying URL  
'http://r.meteo.uni.wroc.pl/src/contrib/rPython_0.0-5.tar.gz' Content  
type 'application/x-gzip' length 37109 bytes (36 KB)  
================================================== downloaded 36 KB  

* installing *source* package ‘rPython’ ...  
** package ‘rPython’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked which: no python3.5-config in (/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin) could not  
locate python3.5-config
```

As you can see now it is looking for python3.5-config, which is the version I specified above.

Also if your python3.5-config file is not in the PATH then you might also want to set the PATH:

```
Sys.setenv(PATH='/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin')
```

You might also need to rename python3.5m-config, because rPython always looks for [pythoncommand]-config, which in my case was python3.5 and not python3.5m, so I just renamed python3.5m-config to python3.5-config and then the rPython package has installed.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is way late, but I believe you have to set the R environment variable, not the bash environment variable. Set it like this: `Sys.setenv(RPYTHON_PYTHON_PATH=3)`

HTH.

EDIT: Nope, that's not it. I'm stumped, too.

Comment: You migth delete the answer then?

Comment: Thanks Nick. For the benefit of anyone else, I gave up trying to change the version of python and used older mail handling methods.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, none of the provided answers worked. I suspect it's because I installed python3 through homebrew (I'm on Mac OSX).
However, this worked:

I edited the `configure.ac` file in the downloaded package and then installed it through `R CMD INSTALL`.

```
MYPYTHONCONFIG=python3-config
MYPYTHON=python3
```